# Voiceover not detecting when adding UIView to UIWindow's subview

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have used common `UIPickerView` for my whole app. So, I have used `UIWindow`

**CODE:**

```
@IBAction func show_Picker(_ sender: UIButton) { //ProfileViewController
   let testController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pick") as! PickerViewController
   UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(testController.view)
}
```

`Voiceover` is not detecting this `UIWindow` subview.

`PickerViewController` is shown but `Voiceover` circulating in `ProfileViewController` itself.

I dont know how to activate `Voiceover` in `PickerViewController`.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Tell VoiceOver a view that makes up a major portion of the screen has appeared with `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: newViewOrNil)`.